# Flex Excel export utf-8 characters using as3xls

Tags: apache-flex, utf-8, export-to-excel, as3xls

I am using as3xls library to export data tables to excel sheet in my flex application. My application is multilingual which contains utf-8 characters.

can anybody help me how to include utf-8 characters in my excel sheet?

The answer of Splash works undoubtedly when accessing the application in firefox and chrome but **does not** work on **Safari**.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 encoding is not supported by the current implementation of [as3xls](https://code.google.com/p/as3xls/). The `saveToByteArray` function uses a BIFF2 (Excel 2.x) stream for encoding which doesn't support UTF-8.

> All Excel file formats up to BIFF5 contain simple byte strings. The
>   byte string consists of the length of the string followed by the
>   character array. ... The encoding of the character array is dependent
>   on the current record, for example taken from the CODEPAGE record.

A quick-fix could be to change the `saveToByteArray()` function in `ExcelFile.as` to

```
public function saveToByteArray(codePageID: int, charSet: String):ByteArray
```

Add these lines after `br.writeTag(bof);`

```
if (codePageID > 0)
{
    var codePage:Record = new Record(Type.CODEPAGE);
    codePage.data.writeShort(codePageID);
    br.writeTag(codePage);
}
```

and change `cell.data.writeUTFBytes(value);` to  `cell.data.writeMultiByte(value, charSet);`

This way you can adjust the character set to your needs.

```
var xls:ExcelFile = new ExcelFile();
...
// write xls with cyrillic characters
var bytes:ByteArray = xls.saveToByteArray(28595, "iso-8859-5");
```

Further reading:

- [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding
- http://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf